# Python PyQt QWebView load site in clicked tab

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

I need your help!

The situation: I have different tabs and in one tab [`"Support"-Tab`] I want to use the QWebView Widget.
But the site should first load when I click on this tab:

> main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from tab-file import Support

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.createTabs()

        widgetLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        widgetLayout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(widgetLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Tabs")
        self.resize(400,400)


    def createTabs(self):
        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()

        support = Support()

        tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        tab2 = support

        self.tabs.addTab(tab1,"tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(tab2,"SUPPORT")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I load the `"Support"-Tab` from this file:

> tab-file.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit


class Support(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Support, self).__init__(parent)

        self.supportTab()


    def supportTab(self):

        view = QtWebKit.QWebView()

        url = "http://www.google.com"
        view.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(view)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
```

Can you please tell me how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `main.py`:

make the `tab2` addressable, and add code to listen to tab change event:

```
    #...
    self.tab2 = support

    self.tabs.addTab(tab1,"tab1")
    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"SUPPORT")
    #
    self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.load_on_show)
```

Then add the action

```
def load_on_show(self):
    idx = self.tabs.currentIndex()
    if idx == 1:
        url = "http://www.google.com"
        print url
        self.tab2.load_url(url)
```

At last, in `tab_file.py`  [i can't use a dash, have to use an underscore!]:

Make `view` addressable, again (`self.view`) and add code

```
def load_url(self, url):
    self.view. load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
```

Does this help?